# Panels vs. Entity View Attachments (EVA)

Tags: 7, views

Just digging into view, panels, contextual filters, etc. do build and render related entities. In this context I got the EVA module and now asking myself if I need EVA when using Panels? In a panel (page) I can include a pane to insert the result of a view - at least that is what I understood so far. Isn't EVA about the same thing? If I don't use Panels I see the point of EVA but if I use Panels anyway do I need EVA?

Thx for help,
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you need a module or not depends on your use case; you certainly don't want to install and enable a bunch of modules that you don't need, as this will slow down your site and can cause other problems.

In this context, if Panels does what you need alone, then you don't need any other modules (and Panels can do so many things that it generally is sufficient by itself).

If you're committed to Panels, there's probably no need to use EVA-- and certainly if you're asking whether there's a need, you should try doing everything in Panels first, as that will be easier to maintain long-term.

EVA would be better if you wanted something more lightweight and just want to make changes for a few things; Panels is more useful if you want to take full control over the layout.  EVA can also be used in circumstances where Panels integration isn't finished (e.g., Revisioning module and Panels' node add/edit forms).

That said, these two modules really aren't all that similar.  Usually the layout modules are considered to be Panels and Context.  Entity View Attachments is really just an extension of the attachment feature provided by the Views module.  In that way, you could think of it as competing with content panes, another type of display provided by Views specifically for Panels (for reference, [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29667/when-to-use-views-attachments-vs-content-panes) relates to the differences between attachments and content panes).

Comment: Thx - that makes sense. So if I already use Panels (what can slow down the site - as I understood) I can include subviews using Pansle. Otherwise I can use EVA.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance with Panels.  For smaller sites, it's fast enough out-of-the-box.  If you have a bigger site, you can learning how the caching feature works and then configure it-- that will make Panels extremely fast, in some cases faster in real-world performance than Drupal without Panels.  Sony Music runs all of their artists' sites on Panels.

Comment: i just managed to get the page execution time to a half only by uninstalling EVA. apparently it goes through all views on a site on every noad view, so if you have more of them, your site cen get pretty slow.